# Jenkins ignoring java command line option for logging. How to fix it?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, slf4j, log-level

I am passing java command line option in Jenkins build configuration in Goals and 
Options as  `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn`

But somehow jenkins is ignoring it and I am getting log levels at INFO.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have other logging properties defined? as logging.properties?

Comment: yes. log4j.xml is declared in src/main/resources

Comment: This file can override default level according to its definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a default level, that Jenkins accepts, but if you define specific implementation properties,as inside log4j.xml, it will override **default** and save logs per definition. for example:

```
<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```